# Join strings with a delimiter only if strings are not null or empty

Tags: javascript, string

This feels like it should be simple, so sorry if I'm missing something here, but I'm trying to find a simple way to concatenate only non-null or non-empty strings.

I have several distinct address fields:

```
var address;
var city;
var state;
var zip;
```

The values for these get set based on some form fields in the page and some other js code.

I want to output the full address in a `div`, delimited by comma + space, so something like this:

```
$("#addressDiv").append(address + ", " + city + ", " + state + ", " + zip);
```

Problem is, one or all of these fields could be null/empty.

Is there any simple way to join all of the non-empty fields in this group of fields, without doing a check of the length of each individually before adding it to the string?

Comment: Why not have all those fields in an object then loop, compare, discard?

Answer (score 455, accepted):

If your definition of "empty" means [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#boolean_coercion) (e.g., `null`s, `undefined`s, empty strings, `0`, etc), consider:

```js
var address = "foo";
var city;
var state = "bar";
var zip;

text = [address, city, state, zip].filter(Boolean).join(", ");
console.log(text)
```

`.filter(Boolean)` is the same as `.filter(x => Boolean(x))`.

If your definition of "empty" is different, then you'll have to provide it, for example:

```
 [...].filter(x => typeof x === 'string' && x.length > 0)
```

will only keep non-empty strings in the list.

---

(obsolete jquery answer)

```
var address = "foo";
var city;
var state = "bar";
var zip;

text = $.grep([address, city, state, zip], Boolean).join(", "); // foo, bar
```

Answer (score 131):

Yet another one-line solution, which doesn't require `jQuery`:

```js
var address = "foo";
var city;
var state = "bar";
var zip;

text = [address, city, state, zip].filter(function(val) {
  return val;
}).join(', ');

console.log(text);
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. Uses native functions. If you're using es6/es2015 it can be shortened to just
 `[address, city, state, zip].filter(val => val).join(', ')`

Answer (score 16):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/) solution: `_.filter([address, city, state, zip]).join()`

Answer (score 5):

[@aga's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19903533/3345644) is great, but it doesn't work in older browsers like IE8 due to the lack of [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in their JavaScript engines.

For those who are interested in **an efficient solution working in a wide range of browsers (including IE 5.5 - 8) and which doesn't require jQuery**, see below:

```
var join = function (separator /*, strings */) {
    // Do not use:
    //      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    // since it prevents optimizations in JavaScript engines (V8 for example).
    // (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)
    // So we construct a new array by iterating through the arguments object
    var argsLength = arguments.length,
        strings = [];

    // Iterate through the arguments object skipping separator arg
    for (var i = 1, j = 0; i < argsLength; ++i) {
        var arg = arguments[i];

        // Filter undefineds, nulls, empty strings, 0s
        if (arg) {
            strings[j++] = arg;
        }
    }

    return strings.join(separator);
};
```

It includes some performance optimizations described on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

And here is a usage example:

```
var fullAddress = join(', ', address, city, state, zip);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
function joinIfPresent(){
    return $.map(arguments, function(val){
        return val && val.length > 0 ? val : undefined;
    }).join(', ')
}
$("#addressDiv").append(joinIfPresent(address, city, state, zip));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pv2ua/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each([address,city,state,zip], 
    function(i,v) { 
        if(v){
             var s = (i>0 ? ", ":"") + v;
             $("#addressDiv").append(s);
        } 
    }
);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple, IE6 (and potentially earlier) backwards-compatible solution without `filter`.

##### TL;DR → look at the 3rd-last block of code

`toString()` has a habit of turning arrays into CSV and ignore everything that is not a string, so why not take advantage of that?

```js
["foo", null, "bar", undefined, "baz"].toString()
```

**→ `foo,,bar,,baz`**

This is a really handy solution for straightforward CSV data export use cases, as column count is kept intact.

---

`join()` has the same habit but let's you choose the joining delimiter:

```
['We built', null, 'this city', undefined, 'on you-know-what'].join('  ')
```

→ **`We built    this city    on you-know-what`**

---

As the OP asking for a nice space after the comma and probably don't like the extra commas, they're in for a `replace`-RegEx treat at the end:

```js
["foo", null, "bar", undefined, "baz"].join(', ').replace(/(, ){2,}/g, ', ')
```

**→ `foo, bar, baz`**

Caveat: `(, ){2,}` is a rather simple RegEx matching all 2+ occurrences of  commas followed by a space – it therefore has the potentially unwanted side-effect of filtering any occurrences of `, ,`  or `,`  at the start or end of your data.

Of that is no concern, you're done here with a neat and simple, backwards-compatible one-liner.

If that is a concern, we need come up with a delimiter that is so far-out that the probability of it appearing twice in your data items (or once at the beginning or the end) approaches zero. What do you think about, for instance, `crazy-ſđ½ł⅞⅝⅜¤Ħ&Ł-delimiter`?

You could also use literally *any* character, probably even ones that don't exist in your local charset, as it is just a stop-signifier for our algorithm, so you could do:

```js
["foo", null, "bar", undefined, "baz"]
  .join('emoji-✊-delimiter')
  .replace(/(emoji-✊-delimiter){2,}/g, ', ')
```

or (in a more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) version of this:

```js
var delimiter = 'emoji-✊-delimiter'
var regEx = new RegExp('(' + delimiter + '){2,}', 'g')

["foo", null, "bar", undefined, "baz"].join(delimiter).replace(regex, ', ')
```