# Convert time in minutes to "d h m" format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got value - 20927, and its have to be in this format - 14d 12h 47m

I tried do math by myself but didn't found any solutions.

Comment: What is this `20927`?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098913/convert-seconds-to-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds I think this is the solution you're after.

Comment: 20927 is value in minutes

Comment: oops misspelling in title i mean minutes not seconds. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/)

```js
const duration = moment.duration(20927, 'minutes')
const durationString = duration.days() + 'd ' + duration.hours() + 'h ' + duration.minutes() + 'm'
console.log(durationString) //"14d 12h 47m"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: An answer should not require a library that isn't tagged or asked for in the OP. This has been answered before.

Comment: Why 90% community in this site so edgy? How can i tag library if i didn't even know how to solve my problem?

Comment: @J.bow—libraries can be suggested in comments and answers, but they should not be the sole basis for an answer. Seconds can be converted to d:h:m:s in one line of code, there's no need for a 4,000 line, 56kB library.

Comment: @RobG definitely agree importing library unnecessarily is not good. But if OP use case is manipulating dates heavily a utility library like moment.js can save a lot of developer time. (Which can be just as important as performance in many cases.)

Also question is tagged as node.js so I assumed library size was not a big factor since it won't be used in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Try [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```
moment(0).add(20927, 'm').format('DD[h] hh[h] MM[m]')
```

Comment: thank you i will try it as well :)

Comment: An answer should not require a library that isn't tagged or asked for in the OP. This has been answered before.

Comment: Could you point me any resources which enforces your argument? Seems pretty ok to me to suggest a library once OP doesn't request for a pure js solution