# Analyzing Date difference between two dates to text : "before: x Days, x Hours, x Minutes"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, date-difference

I have done a lot of research to find code examples for this, or simillar question but I didn't find any.

I have a react app that has some `customer requests` in it, and I want to show next to each request something like: `'before: 2 Days, 4 Hours, 56 Minutes.'`

I want to calculate the difference between the current Date and the time the request was sent, and **analyze** this difference to **days, hours**, and **minutes**.

**note:** The date difference won't be longer than one month.

I know that I can do: `dt1 - dt2` to get the difference, But this returns a long integer which is hard to analyze.

**Edit:**
It suppose to be like this:

```
days + hours + minutes == difference
```

So if you try to convert `days,hours,minutes` to milliseconds and sum them together, it should result simillar difference of `(d1-d2)`

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert seconds to days, hours, minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098913/convert-seconds-to-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds)

Comment: I tried this but it's not sutiable for my case because I want to convert a **difference** to this structure, not just some date which is given in milliseconds.

Comment: it's exactly your case. `dt1-dt2` is the number of milliseconds (ie the *difference*) between the two dates and the linked duplicate converts a number of seconds (I'm sure you are able to convert ms to seconds) to the respective number of days hours minutes and seconds

Comment: Yes, I know, I did that. What I meant is :what should I do after I converted to `days, hours, minutes` ? I get **all**  hours in between the dates, and **all** minutes - which is not what I want. I need it to be : `days+hours+minutes = diffrence` - the sum of all together will be the diffrence. 
So how can I calculate the milliseconds to result this?

Comment: What do you mean by *all* hours and *all* minutes. For something like `123456` seconds you get 34 hours and 2057 minutes? Then you are not doing it as proposed in the linked duplicate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for better human readability.
There are multiple packages that would achieve that.

For your use case user this https://www.npmjs.com/package/humanize-duration

```
humanizeDuration(dt1-dt2) // Will result in what you want
```

Comment: Library suggestions really should be comments.